# How do I directly modify the li inside of a django block?

Tags: django, django-cms

My project.db is corrupt. I have a navigation menu that is being generated by django_cms, and all I want to do is modify the li's in the navigation bar. But because I can't access the html directly, I have no way of doing this.

How do I modify the html of a django block?

this is the code that I have:

> `{% show_menu 0 1 100 100 "menu.html" %}`

I'd like to be able to get into show_menu directly, and modify all of the li's so that I can change their names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you cannot access the HTML? Every Django template tag just uses a template to render its contents. You can override every template Django cms provides.

You can override the default menu.html template as you like, and then you use your custom menu.html template as argument for the show_menu template tag.

See the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/navigation.html)

Comment: I can access the HTML, but the show_menu is getting its information from elsewhere. I believe it may be the DB file, but my db file is corrupt and not showing the page as it should be. I just want to access the li element inside of the show_menu template, without using the CMS at all.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. But if you want to manually adjust the items in the rendered menu, maybe it is better to not use the show_menu template tag at all. You can create a navigation menu yourself, and link to the pages by using the page_url template tag.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Do you think it is possible to do away entirely with all the tags and still keep the same navigation system? Somehow my navigation is being rendered by these template tags, but I have no way of accessing them.

Comment: I would say it depends on the complexity of your navigation. I you don't use nested navigation menus you can just get rid of all the menu_tags. But if you have a lot of dynamic submenus they are very useful. You could also write your own template tags for menu rendering, if you have sufficient Django knowledge.